# How to create dialog which ask for pin if it is correct a following operation will be done

Tags: android, kotlin

This code is where I am creating  Alert dialog. whenever I press ok it crashes .password_dialog has 1 editText and 2 buttons.

```
private fun passwordCheck(position: Int){
        val view=LayoutInflater.from(requireContext()).inflate(R.layout.password_dialog,null,false)
        val builder=AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        with(builder){
            setTitle("Enter your Pin")
            setPositiveButton("Ok"){dialog,which->
                     if(pin_text.text.toString()=="1234"){
                         Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Right Pin",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                     }
                     else{
                         pin_text.requestFocus()
                         pin_text.error="Incorrect"
                     }
            }
            setCancelable(false)
            setNegativeButton("Cancel"){dialog,which->
                 dialog.dismiss()
            }
            setView(view)
            show()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout with the view, for example, an EditText that only accepts numbers and two buttons, accept or cancel.

Then inflate the view

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.id.layout, null, false)
```

Then with that view you get the reference of the buttons and the EditText with

```
val button = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)

//I'm not going to declare all views, but assuming you already did.

button.setOnClickListener {
    if (editText.text.toString.toInt() == 1234 //your correct pin) {
        //CORRECT PIN TODO
    } else {
        editText.requestFocus()
        editText.error = "Incorrect pin"
    }
}
```

Then create the dialog and add that view to it

```
 AlertDialog.Builder(context).setView(view).create().show()
```

Do not add the validation methods in the accept button of the dialog.
They are what are declared as follows.

```
setPositiveButton("Accept"){diálog, which -> }
```

Comment: you can explain a little about the last part how to set custom view with positive and negative buttons

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't explain myself well, but the idea is not to add and you use those buttons to validate the pin, since the dialog will always close. That's why I recommend that you add those buttons in the layout and add their onClickListener there.

Comment: still geting crashes, can we just the code

Comment: Could you edit the question and share the code you have, to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way by which you can create your own dialog with custom layout.
Implement your PIN UI in **custom_dialog.xml** and your logic in **Kotlin** file.

Here is example how you can create custom Dialog.

> custom_dialog.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#424242">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/popup_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Custom Dialog Box"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOpt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/popup_dialog">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_opt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="No"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="32sp"
            android:layout_height="12sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yes_opt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="18dp"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    showDialog()

}

private fun showDialog() {
    val customDialog = Dialog(this)
    customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog)
    customDialog.window?.setLayout(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    val yesBtn = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.yes_opt) as TextView
    val noBtn = customDialog.findViewById(R.id.no_opt) as TextView
    yesBtn.setOnClickListener {
        //Do something here YOUR LOGIC
        customDialog.dismiss()
    }
    noBtn.setOnClickListener {
        customDialog.dismiss()
    }
    customDialog.show()
  }

}
```

[example app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVbZm.png)